# How to use PHP variable inside jQuery for displaying data fetched from MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

Here I have included my code

```
<?php
$var1=$_POST["select1"];
$var2=$_POST["select2"];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Connection Error");
mysql_select_db("cityoffers") or die("Database Error");
if(isset($var1) and empty($var2))
{
$res=mysql_query("select * from product where Category='$var1'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
?>
<ul class="cd-items cd-container">
    <li class="cd-item">
        <img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Item Preview">
<a href="#0" class="cd-trigger"><?php
echo "Company Name:   ".$row[2];?></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="cd-quick-view">
    <div class="cd-slider-wrapper">
        <ul class="cd-slider">
            <li class="selected"><img src="img/item-1.jpg" alt="Product 1"></li>
            <li><img src="img/item-2.jpg" alt="Product 2"></li>
            <li><img src="img/item-3.jpg" alt="Product 3"></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="cd-slider-navigation">
            <li><a class="cd-next" href="#0">Prev</a></li>
            <li><a class="cd-prev" href="#0">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="cd-item-info">
        <h2><?php echo "Company Name:  ".$i++ .$row[2];?></h2>
        <p><?php echo "Product Name:   ".$row[3]."<br>";
echo "Offer Percentage:   ".$row[4]."<br>";
echo "Start Date:   ".$row[5]."<br>";
echo "End Date:   ".$row[6]."<br>"; ?></p>

        <ul class="cd-item-action">
            <li><button class="add-to-cart">Add to cart</button></li>                   
            <li><a href="#0">Learn more</a></li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#0" class="cd-close">Close</a>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/velocity.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

I have included the PHP code in between jQuery. I think while loop is not working. The PHP code fetches the last row alone and displays it. Kindly give me a solution for it.

Comment: [Exploits of a Mom](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: You're reloading all the external .js files for each row returned by the query. You should only load them once.

Comment: If so I will get only one js i.e. jquery design.

Comment: I have changed the code. Still not retrieving.

Comment: Feel like we are missing info, where is the javascript, and which variable is not printing correctly.